# JQuery: ajax request return value "undefined" inside same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value

I have this piece of code:

```
function CallAPI(paramString) {
    var returnVal;
    var jqxhr = $.get(
        "http://url/../"
    )
    .success(function (data) { returnVal = data; })
    .error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert("Error!\n xhr.status = [" + xhr.status + "]\n xhr.statusText: [" + xhr.statusText + "]\najaxOptions = [" + ajaxOptions + "]"); })
    .complete(function () { alert("Request complete."); });

    alert("returnVal: [" + returnVal+ "]");
}
```

The "returnVal" in the last alert is returned as "undefined", but when i debug with Firebug, I see the request response is either "true" or "false". The value is send back from the request as pure string, not specific format (JSON, HTML, ..)

Why does "returnVal" not return the request's response value?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use it outside the ajax call and, as ajax calls are asynchronous, the alert pops up faster than you get the response. You have to use the `returnVal` variable inside the `success` handler, to be sure that you get the value returned by the response.

Comment: Isn't that what I have?: .success(function (data) { returnVal = data; })

Comment: move the alert call inside the handler and you'll get what i mean :)